# Length of a Linearly Independent List $\le$ Length of a Space-Spanning List

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I am reading a theorem in *Linear Algebra Done Right* that proves

> Length of a Linearly Independent List $\le$ Length of a Space-Spanning List

Here is the theorem

$\quad\,$[image]
[image]

I think that the reasoning in the red box is not true because it assumes that $m \le n$ since it says **after step** $m$! The only way that we can reach step $m$ is that we don't run out of $w_i,\,\,i=1,2,...,n$ which already means $m \le n$.

I think that we should assume that the negation is true, i.e. $m>n$, and achieve a contradiction. But I cannot find the paradox! :)

Before this theorem, things introduced in the book are the notion of fields $\Bbb{F}$, lists, $\Bbb{F}^n$, vector spaces, subspace, sums and direct sums of subspaces, linear combinations, span, linear In/dependence. So please write an answer according to theses concepts only not including basis and dimension.

Comment: @SheldonAxler: Please take a look at this.

Comment: H. R.: At step $j$ for $j = 1, \ldots, m$, there must be a $w$ to remove, because otherwise we would have a contradiction (as stated in the second sentence in the red box above). Thank you for pointing out that this could have been explained better. I will rewrite to make this clearer in the next edition of the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that the statement "After step $m$" is begging the question, but you can just remove that sentence from the proof and it works.

But here's a little more exposition:

Let's assume for the sake of contradiction that $m> n$ and then consider the $n$th step.  After this step there are no more $w$'s to remove.  But we know that after every step we have a list that spans $V$.  Thus if we were to add one more $u$, that $u$ must necessarily be a linear combination of $u_1, \dots, u_n$ (by the definition of spanning).  But that contradicts the assumption in the statement of the theorem that $u_1, \dots, u_m$ are linearly independent.  Thus $m\not>n$, so $m\ge n \implies m=n$.

Comment: It is a proof by negation. So I think that $\lnot (m \le n) = m \gt n$! :)